# How to connect to MongoDB with using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm pretty new to mongodb and i'm tryin to figure out how can I connect to my database with python externally.

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]
```

in this example, you connect to your mongodb using a localhost, but I cant figure out how to connect my DB by remote and not locally. (More like, how do I get even a URI to put in there, im digging in mongodb website but im lost)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ ?

Comment: How does your external URI look like (you can give an example format)? Also, refer this: [PyMongo Installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/pymongo/#installation).

Comment: marked the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation:](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/connection-string/), connection string:

```js
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

What you need at least:

- User
- Password
- Host (you are using `localhost`, you will need an `ip` or `address` to connect to a remote database)
- Dabase name

Comment: not `mongodb+srv://`?

Comment: @mousetail not necessary if your are not working with Atlas